# Button to apply the same data to every day of the week

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, where I fill in the data of the first day of the month and then clicking on the "Apply to All" button writes the same values ​​on every day of the month.
Here is a working example:

```js
$('#elemento').click(function() {
  var checkedValues = Array(8).fill(false);
  var textValues = Array(7).fill('');
  var checkedStep = 0;
  var textStep = 0;
  
  $('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value) {
    if (index < 8) {
      checkedValues[index] = $(this).prop("checked");
    } 
    else {
      if (checkedStep == 8) {
        checkedStep = 0;
      }
      $(this).prop('checked', checkedValues[checkedStep++]);
    }
  });
  
  $('tr').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(index, value) {
    if (index < 7) {
      textValues[index] = $(this).val();
    } 
    else {
      if (textStep == 7) {
        textStep = 0;
      }
      $(this).val(textValues[textStep++]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="elemento">Aplica a Todos </button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>sunday</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id='dia'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-10-31
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia1'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-01
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia2'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-02
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia3'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-03
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-04
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia5'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-05
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia6'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-06
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I wanted was to fill in the first day of the month and then, when clicking on the "Apply to All" button, just fill in the days of the week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday) of the month and the days of the end of week were left unfilled.

Can you help?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand, what your goal is. Maybe it would help to change the code to english instead of portugues...

Comment: By the way you select inputs of type ``number`` but it should be ``text``...

Comment: @biberman Yes, I already corrected the input to text. I will change the code to English and explain again

Comment: @biberman I intend that after filling in the first day, click on the apply to all button, and only load the information filled in on weekdays and Saturday and Sunday will be empty with no data. Did you understand?

Comment: So for example, if you fill in "Lanche" the word "apple", you want to apply that word to every Lanche-input, that is not in the column saturday or sunday?

Comment: @biberman I think that's what I said, but I'll give you an example. I'll give you an example, if you fill in snack 5, I want to apply this value to every day of the week, except Saturday and Sunday. Saturday and Sunday, I want them to be unfilled

Comment: I found a solution with drastically modified HTML code. But i'm trying to find a solution with your HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by checking the index of the parent table cell:

```js
$(this).parents('td').index()
```

Because the index starts with a `0`, the weekdays have an index lower than 5. Therefor you should only add the `checked` property or the text value, if the index is smaller than 5:

```js
if ($(this).parents('td').index() < 5) {
  $(this).val(textValues[textStep++]);
}
else {
  textStep++;
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
$('#elemento').click(function() {
  var checkedValues = Array(8).fill(false);
  var textValues = Array(7).fill('');
  var checkedStep = 0;
  var textStep = 0;
  
  $('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value) {
    if (index < 8) {
      checkedValues[index] = $(this).prop("checked");
    } 
    else {
      if (checkedStep == 8) {
        checkedStep = 0;
      }
      
      if ($(this).parents('td').index() < 5) {
        $(this).prop('checked', checkedValues[checkedStep++]);
      }
      else {
        checkedStep++;
      }
    }
  });
  
  $('tr').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(index, value) {
    if (index < 7) {
      textValues[index] = $(this).val();
    } 
    else {
      if (textStep == 7) {
        textStep = 0;
      }
      
      if ($(this).parents('td').index() < 5) {
        $(this).val(textValues[textStep++]);
      }
      else {
        textStep++;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="elemento">Aplica a Todos </button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>sunday</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id='dia'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-10-31
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia1'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-01
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia2'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-02
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia3'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-03
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-04
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia5'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-05
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia6'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-06
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If the first day/column isn't a monday, you could use data attributes (maybe `data-day`) in the belonging table cells like:

```html
<td data-day="4">
```

and check for that attribute instead of the parent index:

```js
$(this).parents('td').data('day')
```

Note: Because in my example the data attribute starts with a `1` instead of a `0` (like the index), the value has to be lower than `6`:

```js
if (parseInt($(this).parents('td').data('day')) < 6) {
  $(this).val(textValues[textStep++]);
}
else {
  textStep++;
}
```

**Working example:**

```js
$('#elemento').click(function() {
  var checkedValues = Array(8).fill(false);
  var textValues = Array(7).fill('');
  var checkedStep = 0;
  var textStep = 0;
  
  $('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value) {
    if (index < 8) {
      checkedValues[index] = $(this).prop("checked");
    } 
    else {
      if (checkedStep == 8) {
        checkedStep = 0;
      }

      if (parseInt($(this).parents('td').data('day')) < 6) {
        $(this).prop('checked', checkedValues[checkedStep++]);
      }
      else {
        checkedStep++;
      }
    }
  });
  
  first_day = false;
  
  $('tr').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(index, value) {
    if (index < 7) {
      textValues[index] = $(this).val();
    } 
    else {
      if (textStep == 7) {
        textStep = 0;
      }

      if (parseInt($(this).parents('td').data('day')) < 6) {
        $(this).val(textValues[textStep++]);
      }
      else {
        textStep++;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="elemento">Aplica a Todos </button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>sunday</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td data-day="4">
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-01
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td data-day="5">
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-02
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td data-day="6">
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-03
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td data-day="7">
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-04
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td data-day="1">
      <div id='dia5'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-05
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td data-day="2">
      <div id='dia6'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-06
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td data-day="3">
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox">2022-11-07
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes this solves an error in the code I put as an example. But what I want is that when applying to everyone, only apply on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday and leave the weekend blank. Can you help?

Comment: I updated my answer. Now it should work, like you want...

Comment: There's a situation here that doesn't work correctly. I will lead by example. If the month in the calendar starts on a Thursday, only in the second week does it apply correctly. I will leave image. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCSou.png). The first Saturday was not supposed to fill. Can still help to verify this problem?

Comment: A solution may be, when generating the calendar, to take the date of all td and identify which day number it belongs to. And then then do the condition like you did. But the problem, I don't know how to get the date of each td when generating the month

Comment: If i leave an empty table cell ``<td></td>`` for the empty days, it works in the stacksnippet. What does the empty days look like in your case?

Comment: It is a calendar that is dynamically generated. The empty days that appear have the date of the days of the previous month. I didn't put the code that generates the calendar because it's long

Comment: The problem is that the month starting on Thursday this code `$(this).parents('td').index()` returns Thursday 1, Friday 2 and Saturday 3 and it shouldn't. Should return Thursday 4, Friday 5 and Saturday 6. The other days behind don't exist, the problem is there

Comment: This should only be the possible, when the first day in the table isn't a monday but instead for example a thursday. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, this is the case, but it is random. The next month starts on a Thursday, but January 2023 already starts on a Sunday.

Comment: Ok, i will watch the problem again...

Comment: But what, if the first day is a saturday or sunday - where do you fill in the data?

Comment: I always fill in the column on day 1, only then does it work

Comment: I updated my answer (second example) - please check it...

Comment: Yes it works, but the problem is that it does not stay dynamically. Because if it starts on a Tuesday it no longer works and generates the calendar dynamically.

Comment: I'm taking the dates of all the tds this way: `var data_idparcela = []; $("[data_idparcela]").each(function() {data_idparcela.push(this.value)});?`. So it returns all the dates of the tds in an array. Now I'm not able to separate the array and then use the function `getDay()`

Comment: I thought, you could also add the data attribute dynamically. Furthermore there is nothing about a function ``getDay()`` in your original question...

Comment: Well no, you're right, but what I'm trying now came after your answer. I think that to complete your answer would be to add this reasoning, but I still only managed to get the dates in td.

Comment: Does it work to set the data attributes dynamically?

Comment: Yes it works, because all columns have the td with the date. This way I say dynamic

Comment: Can you see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74376617/just-fill-in-the-values-in-the-tds-of-the-week) that is related to this one?