# Just fill in the values ​in the tds of the week

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, which when clicking on the apply to all button will only automatically fill in the columns for Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday. Saturday and Sunday should be empty, no data.

```js
$('#elemento').click(function() {
  var checkedValues = Array(8).fill(false);
  var textValues = Array(7).fill('');
  var checkedStep = 0;
  var textStep = 0;
  var data_idparcela = [];
    $("[data-day]").each(function() {data_idparcela.push(this.value)});

    for(var i = 0; i < data_idparcela.length; i++){
       
      var id_data = new Date(data_idparcela[i]);
      var id_data = id_data.getDay();
       
      
      $('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value){
        if(index < 8){
          checkedValues[index] = $(this).prop("checked");
        }else{
          if(checkedStep == 8){
            checkedStep = 0;
          }



          if (id_data >= 1 && id_data <= 5) {
            $(this).prop('checked', checkedValues[checkedStep++]);
          }
          else {
            checkedStep++;
          }

        }
      });
      $('tr').find('input[type="text"]').each(function(index, value){
        if(index < 7){
          textValues[index] = $(this).val();
        }else{
          if(textStep == 7){
            textStep = 0;
          }

          if (id_data >= 1 && id_data <= 5) {
            $(this).val(textValues[textStep++]);
          }
          else {
            textStep++;
          }
        }
      });
     
     }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="elemento">Aplica a Todos </button>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
    <th>sunday</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-01">2022-11-01
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-02">2022-11-02
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-03">2022-11-03
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-04">2022-11-04
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia5'>
        <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-05">2022-11-05
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia6'>
        <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-06">2022-11-06
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <div id='dia4'>
        <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-07">2022-11-07
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Lanche
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox">Ceia
          <input type="text" size="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that when I click the apply to all button, it fills all days, including Saturday and Sunday.

I'm taking the date of each td, and using the getDay() function, to convert the days to a number. But then when I apply the condition the result is that it fills every day.

You should only fill in the columns where the numbering of the days is between 1 and 5, the days that are 0 and 6 (Saturday and Sunday) should not be filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will do the trick for you?

Please note: I removed the (invalid!) duplicate `id`s from your `<div>`elements and replaced them, by `class` attributes.

I also took the liberty of generating your HTML by means of a template string. This helps to avoids a lot of repetitions.

Here is a shortened HTML section with a snippet that generates the rest of the table (the "second part" of the snippet has also been changed, so it will now work with both HTML versions):

```js
// first part, generates the table from a template
// ===============================================
$("table:first tbody").html(Array(7).fill(0).map((_,i)=>{
  let d=String(1+i).padStart(2,'0');
  return `<td>
      <div class="dia">
        <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-${d}">2022-11-${d}
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço<input type="text" size="10"></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox">Almoço<input type="text" size="10"></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)<input type="text" size="10"></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox">Lanche<input type="text" size="10"></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox">Jantar<input type="text" size="10"></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)<input type="text" size="10"></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox">Ceia<input type="text" size="10"></div>
      </div>
    </td>`}).join("\n"));

// second part, works with both, the original and the changed HTML
// ===============================================================
const tbd=$("table:first tbody"),
  inps = $("td:first input",tbd).get(),
  wd=$("table:first th").get().map(t=>t.textContent);


$('#elemento').click(function() {
  $("td",tbd).each(function(j) {
    if(!["Saturday","Sunday"].includes(wd[j]))
      $("input", this).each((i, inp) => $(inp).val(inps[i].value).prop("checked", inps[i].checked));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="elemento">Aplica a Todos </button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th>
        <th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th><th>Sunday</th><th>Monday</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**Second Update**

Here is the version with your rather verbose "original" HTML. It turned out that you got the weekdays wrong in your column headings (`<th>`), so I corrected them here. I also modified my column selection process such that it now evaluates the date value of the `[data-day]`-checkbox in each column in order to identify whether we are dealing with a working day (no weekend!):

```
if(![0,6].includes(new Date($("[data-day]",this).val()).getDay())) { do stuff ...}
```

And here is the complete working snippet again:

```js
// second part, works with both, the original and the changed HTML
// ===============================================================
const tbd=$("table:first tbody"),
  inps = $("td:first input",tbd).get();

$('#elemento').click(function() {
  $("td",tbd).each(function(j) {
    if(![0,6].includes(new Date($("[data-day]",this).val()).getDay()))
      $("input", this).each((i, inp) => $(inp).val(inps[i].value).prop("checked", inps[i].checked));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="elemento">Aplica a Todos </button>
<table>
  <tr>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<th>Wednesday</th>
<th>Thursday</th>
<th>Friday</th>
<th>Saturday</th>
<th>Sunday</th>
<th>Monday</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
<td>
  <div id='dia4'>
    <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-01">2022-11-01
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Lanche
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Ceia
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<td>
  <div id='dia4'>
    <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-02">2022-11-02
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Lanche
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Ceia
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<td>
  <div id='dia4'>
    <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-03">2022-11-03
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Lanche
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Ceia
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<td>
  <div id='dia4'>
    <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-04">2022-11-04
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Lanche
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Ceia
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<td>
  <div id='dia5'>
    <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-05">2022-11-05
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Lanche
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Ceia
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<td>
  <div id='dia6'>
    <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-06">2022-11-06
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Lanche
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Ceia
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>

<td>
  <div id='dia4'>
    <input type="checkbox" data-day='' value="2022-11-07">2022-11-07
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Peq.Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Almoço (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Lanche
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Jantar (Dieta)
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
    
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">Ceia
      <input type="text" size="10">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As you put the code, I can't apply it to mine because it changed the structure a lot. I can't change it, because then it doesn't generate the calendar correctly

Comment: When I run the code here in my project I get the following error `ncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`. 
How can I solve

Comment: Well, it all depends on whether the table really *is* the first table on the page and whether there are just as many headings (`<th>`) as there are `<td>`s. Maybe, check the contents of the array `inps` by placing a `console.log(inps)` after its definition. And, of course, it is essential, that the code is executed *after* the page is loaded.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it keeping my reasoning? Taking the date in each column, using Getday() and then checking? The problem in my code is that when I apply my condition after using Getday, the condition doesn't follow the loop

Comment: Please check again the second part of my answer.

Comment: The problem was really in the td, because it wasn't the first one. I worked with classes to identify the td of the data-day. Thanks